# How to restart alt+f2 dialog in kde after xkill?

Tags: kde, plasma, xkill

The dialog that appears when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> froze (what is it called? minicli?), I then proceeded to kill it by clicking it after running the command xkill, this was the message:

> xkill:  killing creator of resource 0x240017b

I then tried restarting plasma-desktop:

```
killall plasma-desktop
plasma-desktop
```

Thought this seemed to correctly restart the desktop, it didn't solve the problem since <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't launch the launcher.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The program is called krunner and that's what you have to run:

```
krunner
```

Answer (score 1):

As the user who is *logged in*, execute the krunner command in background:

```
rudy@m3800:~/bin$ krunner&
[2] 21108
rudy@m3800:~/bin$ Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
```

Then ALT + F2 or ALT + SPACE should be back.